# Running multiple tasks async in lein

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I have the following aliases

```
:aliases {
        "start-server" ["do" ["ring" "server-headless"]]
        "build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export"]
        "build-html" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export-pages"]
        "build-prod" ["do" ["build-site"] ["cljsbuild" "once" "prod"]]
        "build-js"   ["do" ["cljsbuild" "auto" "dev" ]]
        "watch-stuff" [ "do" ["start-server"] ["auto" "build-html"]]
        "build-dev" ["do" ["build-site"] ["build-js"]  "watch-stuff" ]
            }
```

For some reason I can't run "build-dev" without it stopping at "build-js" How can I run these task parallel or without be suspending in a previous task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lein do` runs things in sequence, to run in parallel you can use [`lein pdo`](https://github.com/Raynes/lein-pdo) instead.